# It does not capture the error of my stored procedure Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I have a procedure with raiserror and spring doesn't catch my mistake or maybe I'm doing something wrong. I leave the code.

**Procedure**

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_CRUD_USERS]
@OPCION INT = 0,
@NOM_USER VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@EMA_USER VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@COD_USER INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @OPCION = 1
            BEGIN
                SELECT * FROM TB_USERS
            END
        ELSE IF @OPCION = 2
            BEGIN
                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TB_USERS WHERE EMA_USER = @EMA_USER)
                    BEGIN
                        IF @NOM_USER IS NULL OR @NOM_USER = '' AND @EMA_USER IS NULL OR @EMA_USER = ''
                            RAISERROR('Ingresar un dato para registrar',16,1)
                        ELSE
                            INSERT INTO TB_USERS VALUES (@NOM_USER, @EMA_USER)
                    END
                ELSE
                    RAISERROR('El email ya existe',16,1)
            END
        ELSE IF @OPCION = 3
            BEGIN
                IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TB_USERS WHERE COD_USER = @COD_USER)
                    BEGIN
                        IF @NOM_USER IS NULL OR @NOM_USER = '' AND @EMA_USER IS NULL OR @EMA_USER = ''
                            RAISERROR('Ingresar un dato para actualizar',16,1)
                        ELSE
                            UPDATE TB_USERS SET NOM_USER = @NOM_USER, EMA_USER = @EMA_USER WHERE COD_USER = @COD_USER
                    END
                ELSE 
                    RAISERROR('El usuario no existe',16,1)
            END
        ELSE IF @OPCION = 4
            BEGIN
                IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TB_USERS WHERE COD_USER = @COD_USER)
                    DELETE FROM TB_USERS WHERE COD_USER = @COD_USER
                ELSE 
                    RAISERROR('El usuario no existe',16,1)
            END
        END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class CrudUserService implements CrudUserDAO{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public ValidateApiResponse MntUser(Integer op, String nom, String ema, Integer cod) {
        ValidateApiResponse vapi = new ValidateApiResponse();
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        try {
            ProcedureCall call = session.createStoredProcedureCall("SP_CRUD_USERS");
            call.registerParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            call.registerParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).enablePassingNulls(true);
            call.registerParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).enablePassingNulls(true);
            call.registerParameter(4, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN).enablePassingNulls(true);
            call.setParameter(1, op);
            call.setParameter(2, nom);
            call.setParameter(3, ema);
            call.setParameter(4, cod);
            vapi.dTable = call.getResultList();
            vapi.Attr = "OK";
            //call.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            vapi.Error = e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return vapi;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class CrudUserController {

    @Autowired
    private CrudUserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/CrudUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ApiResponse CrudUsers(@RequestParam(value = "option", required = true) Integer op,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "nomUser", required = false) String nom, 
                                 @RequestParam(value = "emaUser", required = false) String ema,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "codUser", required = false) Integer cod){

        ValidateApiResponse vapi = new ValidateApiResponse();
        ApiResponse  api = new ApiResponse();

        try {
            vapi = service.MntUser(op,nom,ema,cod);
            if (vapi.Error == null || vapi.Error == "") {
                if (vapi.Attr == "OK") {
                    api.MsjCode = 200;
                    api.Msj = "OK";
                    api.dtCollection = vapi.dTable;
                } else {
                    api.MsjCode = 400;
                    api.Msj = "Dismissed Request";
                    api.MsjDetail = vapi.Attr;
                }
            } else {
                api.Msj = "Internal Server Error";
                api.MsjDetail = vapi.Error;
                api.MsjCode = 500;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            api.Msj = "Internal Server Error";
            api.MsjDetail = e.getMessage();
            api.MsjCode = 500;
        }
        return api;
    }
}
```

**ApiResponse**

```
public class ApiResponse {

    public String Msj;
    public String MsjDetail;
    public List<Object> dtCollection;
    public int MsjCode;

    public ApiResponse() {
        this.Msj = "";
        this.MsjDetail = "";
        this.MsjCode = -1;
        this.dtCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    }       
}
```

**ValidateApiResponse**

```
public class ValidateApiResponse {

    public String Error;
    public String Attr;
    public List<Object> dTable;

    public ValidateApiResponse() {
        this.Error = "";
        this.Attr = "";
        this.dTable = new ArrayList<>();
    }   
}
```

I also have another problem, when he shows me the json does not generate the "keys". Maybe they would tell me that I should create the entity, but I would like it to be something dynamic, maybe add some more data to the procedure and be creating the attribute of that entity, it seems somewhat tedious.
Maybe I'm wrong, any advice?

```
{
    "Msj": "OK",
    "MsjDetail": "",
    "dtCollection": [
        [
            1,
            "AAA",
            "AAA@HOTMAIL.COM"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "BBB",
            "BBB@HOTMAIL.COM"
        ],
        [
            3,
            "CCC",
            "CCC@HOTMAIL.COM"
        ]
    ],
    "MsjCode": 200
}
```

I also want it to be inside brackets and keys [{Cod: 3,Name: "ccc",Email: "ccc@hotmail.com"}] something like that.

Comment: So, first of all I do not know that much of the Spring framework, but I can see a couple of issues in your code. You capture the SQL exception in the `CATCH` bloc in your proc, and you do a `PRINT`. This is "swallowing" the exception, and it will not be raised to the outside world. In pure ADO.NET you can actually capture a `PRINT` message through setting up an eventhandler for `InfoMessage`, but once again, I do not know enough of Spring to say if you can do it there. Best would be to re-raise the error in the procs `CATCH` block, that way your service would catch it.

Comment: but when I do a debug, it doesn't catch the catch in my @Service. It practically passes by, as if there was no error in my procedure. If I enter the same email, it should generate an error, but it does not.

Comment: Sure, it does not catch it because no error "bubbles" up to your service. The error is handled in your SQL `CATCH` block.

Comment: yes, I already changed it. But I still can't get the error or would it be better to create an output parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Because the whole process of your stored procedure was executed *successfully*, no exception is going to be thrown so that you can catch nothing.  An exception - SQLException - may be thrown only if the procedure itself failed to be executed.

Therefore, if some operations (such as DQL or DML) fail to be executed, you should return something in your procedure. (A common way is to return an error code).

**UPDATE**
I am not familiar with T-SQL, but I found an example on MS official website to demo what I said to return status code in your procedure. Its concept is just like HTTP request and response, we always first use status code to identify whether the request has been successfully handled. If something was going wrong, we further check the error message in response.

[Examples of Return Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#examples-of-return-codes)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: console shows me the SQLEXCEPTIONHELPER "Error email", but now it shows me this : "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults".I don't just get the message.